# How to log a django view

Tags: python, django, debugging, logging, django-rest-framework

I'm learning to log and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with the logger in my view since what I've read around doesn't seem to work or I'm just not understanding something.
This are my settings for the logging:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'todo': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

This is the view and the logging part:

```
from rest_framework import generics, filters
from todo import models
from .serializers import TaskSerializer
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def myview(request):
    logger.error('Something went wrong')

class ListTask(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    API view to retrieve list of tasks or create new tasks
    """
    queryset = models.Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['date']
    search_fields = ['description']

class DetailTask(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    """
    API view to retrieve or delete a task
    """
    queryset = models.Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a better way, but you can override the `post()` and `get()` methods of the view and insert logging there. For example:

```py
class ListTask(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    API view to retrieve list of tasks or create new tasks
    """
    queryset = models.Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['date']
    search_fields = ['description']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some logging
        logger.debug("A helfpul message")
        # return super which will run the default get() method for this class
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Have a look at: http://www.cdrf.co/

You can look at all the various DRF View classes and see which methods they support so you know what you can override if you wish to do some logging.

Comment: Thank you but would that be enough? I'm a bit confused about logging itself so I'm not sure if once I add that it's supposed to work. When I run my server I don't see any messages, though, is that normal?

Comment: You can try changing `logger.debug()` to `logger.error()` in the code I provided as your logging level is set to INFO. Give that a try and see what happens. Alternatively, you can change INFO to DEBUG in your logging config

Comment: That worked but do I see the message everytime? If I get it, does it mean I need to fix something?